# How to insert the script, just after the start of the head tag using layout file in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I used this, but it doesn't show my script, just after the head tag start

```
<reference name="head">
  <block type="core/text" name="header_module" as="header_module">
    <action method="setText">
        <text><![CDATA[<script>My_Script</script></text> 
    </action>
  </block>
</reference>
```

example:

```
<head> 
<script> my_script</script> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> <title>home</title> 
....
.....
..
</head>
```

i want to show just after the head tag, not between the other script

Any other methods?
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

To do this you must edit your `head.phtml`
**app/design/frontend/YOUR_PACKAGE/YOUR_THEME/template/page/html/head.phtml**
And put your script top of above template.

Add this to local.xml or your extension's layout xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <block type="core/text" name="header_module" as="header_module">
                <action method="setText">
                    <text><![CDATA[<script>My_Script</script>]]></text>
                </action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

**OR**

To solve your problem:
Use the field Miscellaneous Scripts from `System->Configuration->Design->Head` and put your scripts in there. They will be added before the  tag and you can set different scripts per website or even store views.

Comment: No, I need in layout file,since i have to use in custom module

Comment: Check updated answer

Comment: its same thing which i have mentioned

Comment: Check now. I have updated it

Comment: no,not worked :(

Comment: @RahulSingh This will work now. check it out

Comment: <head>
<script> my_script</script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>home</title>

i want to show just after the head tag, not between the other script

Comment: It's not possible. To do this you must edit your template file and put that script on your desired location.

Comment: @RahulSingh I have updated answer. Take a look

Comment: Thanks, but i think through some other ways we can do this..
thinking..

Comment: have a look for this question too, hope u have some idea
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/106060/how-to-get-the-category-id-from-which-the-product-is-added-into-the-cart

Comment: @RahulSingh Not possible other way. You need to manually do that

Answer (score 2):

**You need to add this code in your xml file:-**

**First Method:-**

```
<layout>  
     <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs">
                <script>custom-script.js</script>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

**Second Method:-**

```
<default>
     <reference name="head">          
           <action method="addItem"><type>external_css</type><name>http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/build/reset/reset.css</name><params/></action>                
           <action method="addItem"><type>external_js</type><name>http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.8.2r1/build/yahoo-dom-event/yahoo-dom-event.js</name><params/></action>
           <action method="addExternalItem"><type>external_js</type><name>http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.8.2r1/build/imageloader/imageloader-min.js</name><params/></action>
           <action method="addExternalItem"><type>external_css</type><name>http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.8.2r1/build/fonts/fonts-min.css</name><params/></action>  
     </reference>           
</default>
```

Answer (score 1):

add bellow code in your layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
       <reference name="head">
          <block type="core/text" name="header_module" as="header_module">
            <action method="setText">
                <text><![CDATA[<script type="text/javascript">alert(111)</script>]]></text> 
            </action>
          </block>
          </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Comment: no,it did the same as used the 
<reference name="head">
  <block type="core/text" name="header_module" as="header_module">
    <action method="setText">
        <text><![CDATA[<script>My_Script</script></text> 
    </action>
  </block>
</reference>

Comment: updated ans pls check now

Comment: pls check and let me know if any change

Comment: no,its coming in between the other script, i want at the top,

Comment: can you share screen shot?

Comment: <head>
 <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
 <meta property="og:description" content="Default Description" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://186.72.95.225/qqqqq/skin/frontend/ultimo/custom/css/styles.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://186.72.95.225/qqqqq/skin/frontend/base/default/css/widgets.css" media="all" />

<script type="text/javascript">alert(111)</script

Comment: its coming like this..

Comment: can you tell me you need after which script?

Comment: just after start of head tag
<head>
<script>my_script</script>
...
...
</head>

Answer (score 0):

You need to use below code

```
<default>
    <reference name="head">
        <block type="core/text" before="-" name="myscript">
            <action method="setText">
                <text><![CDATA[<script type="text/javascript">Your-script</script>]]>
                </text>
            </action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</default>
```

hope it will helpful to you

Comment: don't copy my ans pls

Comment: http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/5-useful-tricks-for-your-magento-local-xml/ Please have a check .

Comment: <head> <script> my_script</script> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> <title>home</title>... ..</head>
 i want to show just after the head tag, not between the other script